# ADB Doesn't recognize Nexus S in Mac 10.6

Tags: android, macos

I just bought the Nexus S with the android version 2.3.3, which I update it to 2.3.4. I use to develop my android apps in my Mac but when i tried to connect my new Nexus S with the ADB it wasn't recognized. Though the ADB worked pretty well with pass android devices.

Moreover, I connected my Nexus S with the ADB under my Linux machine and then worked as a charm.

Any suggestions on how to make the nexus s be recognized to the ADB of my Mac?

Thx in advance!

Comment: I have the exact opposite problem. Works on OS X but not on Trisquel... let's team up

Comment: I Just read that Usb Driver Package Revision 4 is needed to be installed. But I can't find it in my Third party adds-on list.

Comment: First make sure that USB debugging is enabled on the device. Also some devices require a special entry added to ~/.android/asb_usb.ini . Try searching for that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adb devices show offline with Galaxy S4 from Mac OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17872288/adb-devices-show-offline-with-galaxy-s4-from-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the "Usb Driver Package" is for Windows only.

Did you tried to download and use the newest SDK/ADB from http://developer.android.com ?

I had some problems too these days, but after rebooting my phone and reenabling the debug mode ADB worked again.