# adb devices show offline with Galaxy S4 from Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, adb, offline

I'm trying to use adb tool with Samsung Galaxy S4 model on Mac OS X.
But, I can't connect through adb. `adb devices` shows offline all the time.

I tired to update Android tools from Android SDK manager. But, it fails.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Restart the device, eclipse. Mostly this will work fine then.

Comment: try all these points on the list https://urbanjack.wordpress.com/2013/08/01/how-to-fix-androids-adb-devices-are-offline-or-empty-list/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you should make sure that drivers are installed. Google USB Drivers are not available for mac as yet but you can install Samsung Kies that will install drivers then you would be able to run your app on the S4.

You may need some additional steps if you want to access data folder on the S4. Follow steps mentioned in the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867379/android-eclipse-ddms-cant-access-data-data-on-phone-to-pull-files/8896049#8896049) for the purpose.

If you have to root the device then first part of this [**tutorial**](http://www.technobuffalo.com/videos/how-to-turn-a-galaxy-s4-into-a-google-edition-phone/) can help.

Comment: thanks. I'll check about this. Galaxy S4 device is not in my hand now. :)